# Convert datetime to ordinal in python fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

i been had worked with dates. I want to convert datetimes to ordinal but my script fails.

```
from datetime import datetime

date = "2016/12/07 17:45"
date_strip = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M').date()
ordinal = date_strip.toordinal()
# ordinal = 736305
normal_date = datetime.fromordinal(ordinal)
# normal_date = 2016-12-07 00:00:00 not 2016-12-07 17:45:00
```

whats wrong? ca they help me please?

Comment: so ... What's the problem?  Maybe I'm dense, but I'm not seeing the issue here...

Comment: original = 2016/12/07 17:45 after convert ordinal and reconvert from ordinal: 2016-12-07 00:00:00

Comment: Uriel can you explain me please?

Comment: You're using `date()` which only grabs the date. `datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')` without `date()` at the end gives you the right thing

Comment: Replace it and still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`ordinal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal) stores just the date. the ordinal cannot contain the time:

> the proleptic Gregorian ordinal of the date, where January 1 of year 1 has ordinal 1. For any date object d, date.fromordinal(d.toordinal()) == d.

If you want to convert to/from timestamps instead of ordinals, try this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/3579910).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the solution is convert to timestamp

Answer (score 0):

[`datetime.date()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=toordinal#datetime.datetime.date) returns `date` object with same year, month and day, but not the hour, minute and second, i.e **day resolution**. It can be easily seen below.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = "2016/12/07 17:45"
>>> d = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M').date()
>>> type(d)
<type 'datetime.date'>
```

Notice that [`datetime.toordinal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=toordinal#datetime.datetime.toordinal) is the same as `self.date().toordinal()`.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.strptime('2016/12/07 17:45', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
>>> dt.toordinal() == dt.date().toordinal()
True
```

Comment: thanks i think the best way is convert the datetime in timestamp